# Only show unhelpful flags when clicking unhelpful flag count

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, moderation, flags, declined-flags

On user accounts, there is a total count of a user's flags in the following format

> [total flag count] ([unhelpful flag count])

**Both** the total flag count and unhelpful flag counts link to `/users/flag-summary/[uid]`.

[image]

Why the unhappy face?  Because when I want to see the user's *unhelpful flag count* (this is about the only time I peep this) I have to search through *all of their flags*.  Helpful/unhelpful flags are ordered by date, and look exactly the same in the list

[image]

You have to search for "Declined", but the more flags a user has, the more pages there are, so the longer this mess takes.

I would suggest one or both of the following:

1. Have the unhelpful flag count link point to a page with *just the unhelpful flags*
2. In the full flag list, filter unhelpful flags from helpful ones, place them both in their own headered sections, and place the unhelpful flags first.

Comment: +1 for "SAME LEENK `:(`"