# Categorized views in past flags (helpful/declined/disputed)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, declined-flags, flag-history, disputed-flags

I like to know it when I do or see something wrong. So I really like our flagging history (*x* moderator attention flags, *y* deemed helpful, *z* declined, etc.)

I specifically find the declined / disputed flags interesting, because one can learn from his faults. However, now you have to scroll through *all* your good flags, to see your few bad flags.

Can't we have a function to select only the helpful, only the declined or only the disputed? I also consider [blahdiblah's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171730/205264) to be a very good idea: sort on flag type ('not an answer', 'spam', etc.) too.

Comment: This idea sounds good to me. Can anyone speak to the difficulty in implementing it?

Comment: When I imagine a database with votes, which have a `userId` to link to a user, and a `status` which says whether it's declined, disputed, et cetera... this is just selecting a specific `status`, which is like five minutes work. But it might be nastier, and I can't see SE's code :(

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120297/change-helpful-flags-line-to-include-number-of-declined-flags

Comment: Actually, the flagging system is currently being revamped under the hood, so it'll probably involve more than that.

Comment: another related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168107/only-show-unhelpful-flags-when-clicking-unhelpful-flag-count

Comment: As BoltClock says, it sounds like the flagging system has overgrown its original design and is being rebuilt. That would need to be completed first before something like this is implemented, as well as a bunch of other flagging improvements that have been requested. I agree that this sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn any updates on this?

Comment: Related/similar to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92484/flagging-summary-improvement-filters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was implemented today (thanks to Oded) and you are now able to filter your flag history by using links in the sidebar.

Answer (score 16):

While we're at it, you might as well add **categorizing by flag type**.

It'd be nice to see all of my interesting 'other' flags, helpful or not, without having to wade through the huge mass of 'not an answer' flags.

Answer (score 11):

I've written [a userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6203/sort-flags-by-type) that utilizes [nicael](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259214/nicael)'s [pagination/sorting bookmarklets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171720/categorized-views-in-past-flags-helpful-declined-disputed/250687#250687) to add this to your flag page:

[image: Sort flags by type]

Just be careful not to click the buttons too fast – because you're requesting every single page of flags, SE might IP rate-limit you for a few minutes. However, it only happened to me once, and I must have clicked those buttons 50 or 60 times with 25 pages of flags while writing this, so it can't be too aggressive on that front.

Comment: Good job :) once I have free time, was going to implement [this my request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274759/could-we-have-sorting-flags-by-categories) :)

Answer (score 10):

I think it's just the great idea.

I made a script which will load all of your helpful/ declined/ disputed flags. To use, first go to your flags history (`http://{some-se-site-there}.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/your-id`).

Then run one of the following scripts.

To show declined:

```
javascript:var pn=parseInt($(".pager.fr > a:nth-last-child(2)").attr("href").replace("?page=",""));$("#mainbar").text("");for(var i=1;i<pn+2;i++){$("#mainbar").append('<div id="mainbar'+i+'"></div>');$("#mainbar"+i).load(location.href+"?page="+i+" #mainbar > .flagged-post:has(span.Declined)", function(){$(".pager.fr").remove()});}
```

To show helpful:

```
javascript:var pn=parseInt($(".pager.fr > a:nth-last-child(2)").attr("href").replace("?page=",""));$("#mainbar").text("");for(var i=1;i<pn+2;i++){$("#mainbar").append('<div id="mainbar'+i+'"></div>');$("#mainbar"+i).load(location.href+"?page="+i+" #mainbar > .flagged-post:has(span.Helpful)", function(){$(".pager.fr").remove()});}
```

To show disputed:

```
javascript:var pn=parseInt($(".pager.fr > a:nth-last-child(2)").attr("href").replace("?page=",""));$("#mainbar").text("");for(var i=1;i<pn+2;i++){$("#mainbar").append('<div id="mainbar'+i+'"></div>');$("#mainbar"+i).load(location.href+"?page="+i+" #mainbar > .flagged-post:has(span.Disputed)", function(){$(".pager.fr").remove()});}
```

---

Also: the following one just loads all of your flags on one page, so you can use your browser search to find your flags of different types (e.g. type "not an answer" in your browser search to easily navigate between your NAA flags):

```
javascript:var pn=parseInt($(".pager.fr > a:nth-last-child(2)").attr("href").replace("?page=",""));$("#mainbar").text("");for(var i=1;i<pn+2;i++){$("#mainbar").append('<div id="mainbar'+i+'"></div>');$("#mainbar"+i).load(location.href+"?page="+i+" #mainbar", function(){$(".pager.fr").remove()});}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain I got two declined flags last night. However, I was only able to find one of them.

Because my flag history currently has pending flags that go back at least 15 pages (most of them have been handled, but not all), trying to find the rare exception among a huge list of helpful NAA and/or comment flags is really challenging.

How can I decide to delete vote an answer that a mod declined? How can I learn from a mistake if the declined flag is buried? Perhaps I'm even remembering wrong about what my flag count was before I went to sleep?

The high volume flaggers need this feature, which makes it, in my mind, a priority. There should be more rewards for the users who work hard to keep their Stacks clean.