# What happens to positively received meta feature requests?

Tags: support

I recently added two positively received feature requests to this meta site:

- [Don't lock votes on Meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171694/205264)
- [Categorized views in past flags (helpful/declined/disputed)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171720/205264)

On a given moment, these questions weren't 'hot' anymore, so nobody looks at them anymore - or that's how it looks to me. What happens to positively received feature requests and how long does that take, on average?

Comment: The StackExchange developers regularly watch this tag and decide whether or not they want to make the recommended changes. I dont think it can easily be answered regarding how long it takes on average for the request to be implemented because it highly depends on the priority the team places on the request/feature.

Comment: @JoshMein okay, can you make this an answer?

Comment: @JoshMein: 6 - 8 weeks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now it's up to SE to evaluate your requests, determine their feasibility and respond. There are four potential responses:

- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
- [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)
- [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Regardless of the type of response, a SE employee will also typically post an answer with details on their reasoning. If you're lucky, the answer will simply be:

> This will be in the next build

SE monitors the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag on all Metas, and that doesn't have much to do with the hotness of the question. I'm *guessing* highly upvoted requests take priority, but there's no guarantee that a highly upvoted request will be implemented.

Sometimes it takes them a while to respond, 6-8 weeks is the average.

Comment: *Note: 6-8 Weeks is an approximate measure, and does not necessarily reflect the views of SE, or it's developers.*

Comment: Just curious, does the same happen with _answered_ [tag:feature-request]s? I came across [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5551/205264), for example.

Comment: @CamilStaps I think that one is long forgotten, if you want to bring new attention to it you could set a bounty. Also, use `[meta-tag:feature-request]` to autolink to meta tags, the link in your comment points to the (non existent) main site feature-request tag.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I meant this merely as an example, what happens in general to feature-requests with an accepted answer? Does the SE team evaluate those too?

Comment: @CamilStaps I don't think having an accepted answer or not is significant, remember an answer being accepted only tells us that one person (the asker) found it useful, nothing else. For example they declined my bug/feature request [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150180/the-vote-fraud-script-breaks-legitimate-polling-questions-a-serial-downvoters), although the accepted answer would be a very simple and elegant solution.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Very useful!