# How do I filter new responses to my flags?

Tags: support

Is there a way to see which of the responses to my flags are new? (for example, since my last check).

I sometimes check responses to my flags to see what was flagged incorrectly, but there is no way to filter out flags that I have already seen.

For example, I know that last time I've checked I had: 100 helpful, 10 disputed, 10 declined.
Next time I check I see: 101 helpful, 10 disputed, 11 declined. How do I know which one was the new declined one?

Comment: I guess it is not possible by now.

Comment: The only thing you can do is hover over the "helpful" etc. to get the time of the flag handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're ordered by the date of the post that was flagged, there's currently no way to sort them differently.

However, I can see some value in being able to sort ascending / descending by the time you submitted the flag, or by the types (accepted, pending, disputed, etc). While there's some chance that being able to see just disputed or declined flags would encourage more argument over why they were handled a certain way, there is a good bit of educational value in being able to see which ones were deemed helpful.

If you really like the idea and want to put some work into a proposal of how it would work (and possibly think of any negatives if it were implemented), then I do encourage you to submit a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to ask for it. There *is* an open feature request to [sort by type](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171720/categorized-views-in-past-flags-helpful-declined-disputed), but I couldn't find one to sort by the time the flag was submitted or acted upon.