# Add filtering and/or sorting to flags responses

Tags: feature-request, flags, sorting, filtering

Following Tim's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187475/224773).

Would it make sense to add filtering and sorting to https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/`id` page?

Currently the only information user effectively gets is the amount of raised flags in each category: how many were helpful, disputed, declined. User can also see which of all the flags were helpful and which are not, but not in a convenient way, in my opinion.

I think it would be better to allow users to:

1. Filter flags responses to "declined" only or "disputed" only. For example, by clicking on "disputed" or "declined" count.
2. Sort flag responses by the time of those responses being handled (rather than currently - by the time of the flag raising), and possibly separating new flag responses (new from last visit, or at least for a current day).

Above two steps should help users learn easier which flags were raised improperly.

Comment: There are a lot of answers regarding looking at flag history on [this question, which asks for the use cases of looking at your own profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186149/what-is-your-primary-use-for-the-user-profile-page-its-getting-a-redesign). You might consider adding an answer and/or comment there; I think this is a fine idea and would go hand in hand with the aims of that question.